# Bazel fetch issue while compiling Tensorflow

Tags: compilation, tensorflow, bazel

I'm compiling the latest Tensorflow from source. After the configure step I'm facing the following error:

> ERROR:
>   com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException:
>   error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension
>   file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package
>   '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': Error downloading
>   [http://bazel-mirror.storage.googleapis.com/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/5ca1dab6df9ad02050f7ba4e816407f88690cf7d.tar.gz,
>   https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/5ca1dab6df9ad02050f7ba4e816407f88690cf7d.tar.gz]
>   to
>   /home/xyzuser/.cache/bazel/_bazel_xyzuser/cb1e63cb5e61cab49a9fd2f5ba92d003/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/5ca1dab6df9ad02050f7ba4e816407f88690cf7d.tar.gz:
>   All mirrors are down: [java.lang.NullPointerException].

This stems from the bazel_clean_and_fetch() in configure file:

```
bazel fetch "//tensorflow/... -//tensorflow/contrib/nccl/... -//tensorflow/examples/android/..."
```

Same error replicates if I simply do `bazel fetch //...`

My system is behind a proxy and I've set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY in the env.

**bazel version:**
Build label: 0.4.4- (@non-git)
Build target: bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar

**Operating System:**
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Any insights would be helpful as I'm new to Bazel and Tensorflow.

Comment: Can you try again? Maybe it was a transient error. If it's not, please file a bug on our github page, and CC drpngx@, gunan@ and jart@.

Comment: It's not a transient error. I have filed it on github https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7497